# How to transfer a Non Fungible token between accounts in R3 Corda?

Tags: corda

I have created a `Non fungible` `Evolvable token`, shown below

```
@BelongsToContract(PropertyStateTokenTypeContract::class)
data class PropertyState1(
        val landTitle: String,
        val location: String,
        val price: String,
        val maintainer: Party,
        override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier,
        override val fractionDigits: Int = 0
) : EvolvableTokenType() {
    companion object {
        val contractId = this::class.java.enclosingClass.canonicalName
    }

    override val maintainers: List<Party> get() = listOf(maintainer)
}
```

I have issued this token from a node(PartyA) to an account by using a `tokenPointer` as shown below

```
val TestAccount = subFlow(OurAccounts()).filter {  it.state.data.name == nameOfAccount  }.last()

val anonymous_party = subFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(TestAccount.state.data))
val propertytokentype = a.state.data.toPointer<PropertyState1>()

val PropertyToke  = propertytokentype issuedBy ourIdentity heldBy anonymous_party

val issue = subFlow(ConfidentialIssueTokens(listOf( PropertyToke)))
```

Now I want to transfer this token to an account which is under PartyB So how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1.
Prepare query criteria to retrieve the non fungible token from the vault.

```
QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria().withUuid(Arrays.asList(tokenId)).withStatus(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED);
```

Step 2.
Retrieve the non fungible token from the vault.

```
// grab the ticket off the ledger
StateAndRef<T20CricketTicket> stateAndRef = getServiceHub().getVaultService().
                queryBy(T20CricketTicket.class, queryCriteria).getStates().get(0);
```

Step 3: get the pointer to the token

```
T20CricketTicket evolvableTokenType = stateAndRef.getState().getData();

//get the pointer to the T20CricketTicket
TokenPointer tokenPointer = evolvableTokenType.toPointer(evolvableTokenType.getClass());
```

Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);

Step 4 : create a transactionBuilder

```
//create a transactionBuilder
TransactionBuilder transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
```

Step 5: transfer the non fungible token from one account to other

```
//transfer the non fungible token from seller to buyer
//this add inputs and outputs to transactionBuilder
MoveTokensUtilitiesKt.addMoveNonFungibleTokens(transactionBuilder, getServiceHub(), tokenPointer, buyerAccount);
```

Complete sample is available in the Corda repo [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Accounts library has 2 good examples about using accounts with Tokens SDK:
https://github.com/corda/accounts/tree/master/examples/tokens-integration-test/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/examples/tokensTest

Here they transfer a fungible token between 2 accounts, in your case use the non-fungible version of the flow (i.e. `MoveNonFungibleTokens`): https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/32e7ae0044ce3b7c8640154dc333e61261251371/examples/tokens-integration-test/src/integrationTest/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/examples/tokensTest/IntegrationTest.kt#L134

Also make sure that you specify the `changeHolder` in the flow; if your sending account has 1 token with quantity 5 and you only want to send quantity 2, then the change must go back to your sending account, if you leave the `changeHolder` empty; the `MoveNonFungibleTokens` flow will assign the change to the initiating node.

Comment: which is the table updated in the receiver's Node while sharing an account .?

Comment: The table is called `accounts`.